# how to find a Borel function $f$ such that $a(t) = f(b(t))$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $b(t)$ be a non-increasing, right-continuous and positive function on $(0,\infty)$ (clearly, it is Borel) and $a(t)$ be a measurable function on $(0,\infty)$. Moreover, $a(t)$ is a constant on an interval when $b(t)$ is a constant on this interval.
Can we find a Borel function $f:\sigma(b(t))\rightarrow R$ such that $a(t) = f(b(t))$?

Answer (score 0):

In general, no: if $L$ is the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), let $b=2-L$ and $a=2+1_{S}$, where $1_S$ is the indicator function of a non-Borel subset $S$ of the Cantor set $C$. Then $a$ is non-Borel and constant on all the intervals where $b$ is constant (i.e. on $\Bbb R\setminus C$), but the RHS you require is clearly a Borel function.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, what do you mean RHS?  Could u tell me in which case we can find such a Borel function?

Comment: And, I understand a is non-Borel. But how do you know f is not Borel?

Comment: RHS=right hand side (of an identity). I know $a$ is not Borel because $\{x\,:\, a(x)\ge1\}=S$, which is not a Borel set by definition. $f$ **is** Borel, because you said it.

Comment: Clear now. THX.  But do you know for which case there exists such an $f$?  how about when $a(t)$ is Borel?